# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I am getting RecusionError in below program, I am not able to figure out why. 
Request help from experts.

calling method foo of Base class from Derived class results in **RecusionError**

```
BaseKill():
    def foo(self):
        print('what is wrong with jpython')
        return self.bar()
    def bar(self):
        print('just chill bar')
        return None

class Derived(BaseKill):
    def bar(self):
        print('I am bar')
        self.foo()
        self.hello()
    def hello(self):
        print('say Hi')


if __name__== '__main__':
    print('what')
    b=BaseKill()
    b.foo()
    c = Derived()
    c.bar()
```

Comment: BaseKill.foo() actually calls Derived.bar() when you call Derived.bar() in the first place, resulting in a infinit/recursion.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo thanks, but how I tell python to get bar from its own class.

Comment: answer updated with info on @staticmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `class Derived(BaseKill)` the `class Derived()` now "inherrits" the methods from `class BaseKill`.

Including `foo()` and `bar()`.

However you have `bar()` defined in `class Derived()` which takes precedent over the "inherrited `bar()`"

Basically this is similar as doing the following

```
class Derived():
    def foo(self):
        print('what is wrong with jpython')
        return self.bar()    
    def bar(self):
        print('I am bar')
        self.foo()
        self.hello()
    def hello(self):
        print('say Hi')


if __name__== '__main__':
    print('what')
    c = Derived()
    c.bar()
```

From this code you can clearly see that `bar()` is calling `foo()` which in turn is calling `bar()` again. This is an infinite/recursion.

The error you are seeing is correct.

In your original code you can include some `print` statements to get the name of the class represented by `self`, example `print(self.__class__.__name__)`. This can help you further understand the class inheritance.

You might want to look at `@staticmethod` for `BaseKill.bar()`, however this will change the functionality, so ensure you test this thoroughly to ensure this is what you want:

```
class BaseKill():
    def foo(self):
        print('what is wrong with jpython')
        return BaseKill.bar()
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print('just chill bar')
        return None

class Derived(BaseKill):
    def bar(self):
        print('I am bar')
        self.foo()
        self.hello()
    def hello(self):
        print('say Hi')


if __name__== '__main__':
    print('what')
    b=BaseKill()
    b.foo()
    c = Derived()
    c.bar()
```

[More information about `@staticmethod` here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

Alternatively you can do the following for `foo()` in `BaseKill`:

```
class BaseKill():
    def foo(self):
        print('what is wrong with jpython')
        return BaseKill.bar(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leason learned: **while calling method of same class, use its name in-front of them, like BaseKill.bar(self)** *to prevent error due to overriding of methods*

```
BaseKill():
        def foo(self):
            print('what is wrong with jpython')
            #return self.bar() ----Error 'self' referred to Calling class
            return BaseKill.bar(self) #referred to same class method

        def bar(self):
            print('just chill bar')
            return None

    class Derived(BaseKill):
        def bar(self):
            print('I am bar')
            self.foo()
            self.hello()
        def hello(self):
            print('say Hi')


    if __name__== '__main__':
        print('what')
        b=BaseKill()
        b.foo()
        c = Derived()
        c.bar()
```